# MATLAB Piecewise Linear Transformation Function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have generated a function to apply a piecewise linear transformation to an image. Based on this function, I am unsure if it is performing correctly. Sometimes the entire image shows up as white and all pixels listed as 255. Other times, the output image appears but results vary. Due to the varying results, I believe there is an issue with my function. The code for the function is here:

```
function T = piecewise_transform(f,n,r1,s1,r2,s2,r3,s3)

% breakpoints: (0,0),(r1,s2),(r2,s2),(r3,s3),((L-1),(L-1))

% to get alpha, beta, etc, don't suppress echoing (remove ; )

% find the parameters of each line

L = 2^n;

% s = a*r+b

a1 = ((s1-0)/(r1-0));
b1 = ((s1/r1)); 
a2 = ((s2-s1)/(r2-r1));
b2 = ((s1*r2)-(s2*r1)/(r2-r1)); 
a3 = ((s3-s2)/(r3-r2));
b3 = (((s3-s2)/(r3-r2))*(s2/r2));
a4 = (((L-1)-s3)/((L-1)-r3));
b4 = (((L-1)-s3)/((L-1)-r3)*(s3/r3));

% put all parameters in two vectors

A = [a1,a2,a3,a4]
B = [b1,b2,b3,b4]

[row,col] = size(f);
T = f;

for i = 1:row
    for j=1:col

    % find which line to use

    %line 1
    if f(i,j) < r1
        flag = 1;
    end

    % line 2
    if f(i,j) > r1 && f(i,j)<r2
       flag = 2;
    end

    % line 3
    if f(i,j) > r2 && f(i,j)<r3
       flag = 3;
    end

    % line 4
    if f(i,j) > r3 && f(i,j)<(L-1)
       flag = 4;
    end

    T(i,j) = (A(flag)*f(i,j) + B(flag));
   end
end

T = uint8(T);

imshow(T)
```

Here are the results of some of my tests:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Based on my code, why am I receiving varying results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a multiple problems in the code causing things to behave strangely.

First, there is no error checking for things like Inf's and NaN's when defining a1:a4 and b1:b4. If you pass values to the function that cause division by a zero then you will receive Inf or in the case of  0/0 then you will receive NaN.

Second, the logic in the `if` statements do not take into account when the value at `f(i,j)` is equal to values of either `r1,r2,r3`or `L-1`.

Third, there is no normalization of `T(i,j)`on the scale of 0 - 255. This means that if your value is larger than 255 and you cast T as uint8 it will become 255. This is likely why your first image was all white. `imread` interprets 255 as white and 0 as black.

Also this code will only be good for black and white images. If you wish to use RGB then you will have to take into account a 3rd color dimension.